# The S parameters of an attenuator--but what is actually wrong with it?

Tags: rf

I have measured S parameters of an 10 dB attenuator on hand--please see the attachment.

- In my view, this attenuator is not performing as expected, e.g., |S12| / |S21| is not giving 10dB attenuation but rather it is giving ~20 dB attenuation (but varying over frequency).
- the reflections, |S11|, are just too high.  Also |S22| are just too high in low frequency, but high frequencies it is low.

But my question is, if you are asked to describe the characteristics of such an attenuator, then what else would you say?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: Are you comparing dB amplitude with dB power? In which case you will be a factor of two off.

Comment: I have the measurement results of a "good" 10 dB attenuator, which shows the flat -10 dB attenuation level of |S21| / |S12|. So, I "think" the VNA converts in proper dB sense as 20*log10(abs(Sxx)), where abs(Sxx) is in amplitude sense.

Comment: Is this a coaxial attenuator, did you use the correct torque wrench to make all connections (cable to VNA, VNA to DUT, VNA to standards during calibration)? If this is an on-chip attenuator or you're using microprobes to connect to it, are you sure you landed the probes correctly?

Comment: It's a coaxial attenuator. Yes, I made sure all the connections are good.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is very likely that port 1 of the attenuator has a bad connection, possibly due to a broken connector.  Somewhere, the RF is passing through a capacitive coupling instead of a direct connection.

Evidence:

1) Attenuation is higher than expected - 20dB instead of 10dB

2) The match is asymmetric - port 2 is well matched, port 1 is basically reading an open circuit.

You can verify this with a multimeter.  A healthy attenuator will read some resistance (say, <100 ohm) between the input and output, and similar between each input and ground.  Your attenuator, I believe, will read an open circuit between input and output.